# Getting dishes ordered by a user in python

Tags: python, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I actually want the dishes a particular user ordered from the given dataset. For example, if I give user_id = U1077, I want to get the dishes he ordered in return. I am using python code. Can anyone help me with this.

| user_id | dish |
| --- | --- |
| U1077 | Prawns Biryani |
| U1077 | Chilli Potatoes |
| U1077 | Paneer Multani Tikka |
| U1068 | Kadaai Paneer |
| U1068 | Veg biryani |
| U1068 | Mushroom Malai Tikka |
| U1067 | Chilli Mushroom |
| U1077 | Lacha Paratha |

I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried googling "getting subset of pandas dataframe" or "filtereing pandas dataframe"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Comment: Downvoted - please edit your title to be a question regarding your coding issue. Futher more "voted to close" due to duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your data that you provided has been saved to a csv file. Added one more line for clarity: U1077 Prawns Biryani.
With the help of Pandas I read them, this is how they look:

```
  user_id                  dish
0   U1077        Prawns Biryani
1   U1077       Chilli Potatoes
2   U1077  Paneer Multani Tikka
3   U1077        Prawns Biryani
4   U1068         Kadaai Paneer
5   U1068           Veg biryani
6   U1068  Mushroom Malai Tikka
7   U1067       Chilli Mushroom
8   U1077         Lacha Paratha
```

Next, I used explicit [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc) indexing, where row indices are in square brackets on the left (in this case, this is a Boolean mask, which is obtained from the expression df['user_id'] == 'U1077'), on the right is the name of the column. I also applied unique() at the end to get only [unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) values if the dish was ordered several times. Result list:

```
['Prawns Biryani' 'Chilli Potatoes' 'Paneer Multani Tikka' 'Lacha Paratha']
```

if you remove unique() you will get all rows with the selected 'user_id':

```
0          Prawns Biryani
1         Chilli Potatoes
2    Paneer Multani Tikka
3          Prawns Biryani
8           Lacha Paratha
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dishes.csv', header=0)

print(df)

aaa = df.loc[df['user_id'] == 'U1077', 'dish'].unique()

print(aaa)
```